# Queries and stages on Spark UI in Apache Spark Structured Streaming stuck

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Apache Spark Structured Streaming (3.1.2) on the EMR cluster (6.14). Spark structured streaming streams data from Apache Kafka to the Delta Lake table. When I open Spark UI, I see the following pictures. Many queries and stages are in active status but if I open details about tasks in stage, all tasks are successful. Queries are finished successfully, but spark UI shows that it is in active status. Does anybody face the same problem?
[image: queries]
[image: stages]
[image: tasks]

I expect that all queries should be completed because I don't have any trouble with new data coming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more logs
Click on stderror and stdout on spark ui, it may show what’s the problem here.
It could be anything a firewall issue or file system or some Infrastructure related.